# How to add a data entry line in Word 2016?

Tags: microsoft-word

How can I add a horizontal line, a line you can write text on, next to the existing text?  For example:

Name___________
customer ID___________

I used underscores in this case, but I cannot write on the line. Can I add a line that I can write text *on*, that appears like above? Not under the line, not above, but next to the text and I can write on it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is [a nice little guide](http://wordmvp.com/FAQs/TblsFldsFms/LinesInForms.htm) to help you on your quest. It is a little outdated, but should work relatively the same (button locations may moved slightly if in a newer Office version). But I recommend (as an option listed on this) is to create a table with with the majority of it with invisible borders EXCEPT the border below the cell where you want to type (as it shows under number or method 2 in the PDF).

Method 2 to create the example you gave.

1. Insert → Table → 4x1. Hold the Alt Key and Drag the Divider for columns 1&2 so the second column is bigger for typing in. Hold the Alt Key and Drag the Divider for columns 3&4 so the fourth column is bigger for typing in.
2. Type in 1st column "Name: " and in the 3rd column "Customer ID: "
3. Drag and select the entire table (it should highlight). Right Click the selection → Click drop down menu on borders, which is a little 2x2 box at the top menu → Select "No Borders"
4. Click into the second column (where you'd type Name) right click the cell → Click drop down menu on borders → Select "Bottom Border." Note: It is invisible now. Do the same for the fourth column.
5. Modify it to your heart's content. I'd select the 1st and 3rd column and Align it to the Right. I would also bold them. I'd select the 2nd and 4th column and Align it to the Left. Readjust the dividers to better fit the way you want.